# WooCommerce checkout doesn't display correctly in local copy of WordPress site using DevKinsta

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, localhost

#### Aim

To create a local copy of a WordPress site using DevKinsta.

#### Issue

Everything is working currently in the local site copy except for the checkout page. Something can be added to the basket without problems, then the checkout page shows the heading for 'Enter billing details' and nothing else. No payment options or input fields.

When I right click Inspect -> Console in the browser, I get:

- GET 500 error for the checkout URL
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setDefaults')

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setDefaults')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ajax.js:2:22)
    at i (jquery.js:2:27362)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2:28121)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2:29914)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2:30276)
```

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMethod')

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addMethod')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:176:22)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317:7)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3536:13)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3552:9)
```

[This WooCommerce docs link](https://avada.io/woocommerce/docs/fix-checkout-page-not-working.html) suggests themes and plugins can be common causes of JavaScript errors with WooCommerce, however, since the site is working in production with the same plugins/theme and doesn't show the same errors it would suggest an issue with the local copy set up.

#### Have tried:

- Checking the SSL/HTTPS, DevKinsta has an SSL/HTTPS option which registers fine in the browser.
- Replacing all the URL references in the database and in the WordPress files

#### Running on:

macOS, Chrome/Safari

#### Update

It appears to be an issue with the custom theme. Changing the theme to the default shows the payment input fields correctly. I've noticed that the minimum PHP version for DevKinsta is 7.2 whereas the production version is running 7.0. Is there somewhere within the custom theme specifically that I might find the issue?

Comment: Please consider providing the context of the errors `Uncaught TypeError`. Any code or stack trace could be helpful to identify your issues.

Comment: @HardcoreGameDev thank you, I've updated it with the context.